# yadcf plugin - using select filter_type with custom_func

Tags: yadcf

Using the [yadcf](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf) plugin, is it possible to have the "select" **filter_type** with a custom function defined for **custom_func** to perform the filtering/matching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes

For example

```
var table = $('#sample-table');
var dtable = table.DataTable();

yadcf.init(dtable, [{
    column_number: 0,
    select_type: "chosen",
    text_data_delimiter: ";",
    filter_type: 'custom_func',
    custom_func: myCustomFilterFunction
}]);


function myCustomFilterFunction(filterVal, columnVal) {
    const items = columnVal.split(';');
    return items.some(function(arrVal) {
        return filterVal === arrVal;
    });
}
```

Read from the docs

```
* filter_type
            Required:           false
            Type:               String
            Default value:      'select'
            Possible values:    select / multi_select / auto_complete / text / date / range_number / range_number_slider / range_date / custom_func / multi_select_custom_func / date_custom_func
            Description:        The type of the filter to be used in the column


* custom_func
            Required:           true (when filter_type is custom_func / multi_select_custom_func / date_custom_func)
            Type:               function
            Default value:      undefined
            Description:        should be pointing to a function with the following signature myCustomFilterFunction(filterVal, columnVal, rowValues, stateVal) , where `filterVal` is the value from the select box,
                                `columnVal` is the value from the relevant row column, `rowValues` is an array that holds the values of the entire row and `stateVal` which holds the current state of the table row DOM
                                , stateVal is perfect to handle situations in which you placing radiobuttons / checkbox inside table column. This function should return true if the row matches your condition and the row should be displayed) and false otherwise
            Note:               When using multi_select_custom_func as filter_type filterVal will hold an array of selected values from the multi select element
```

Comment: OK. From the documentation, I assumed that custom_func can only be used with custom_func / multi_select_custom_func / date_custom_func filter_type. Perhaps the documentation can say that it's usable with all filter types but only required with those three. Anyway. This works with the select filter type (without the extra filter_type: 'custom_func' in the provided example.

Comment: it is as it says in the docs, the `filter_type: 'select',` was there by mistake, feel free to clarify the docs in a PR on github repo page